# query to search for occurance of any word of a search string

Tags: couchbase-lite

I have the following documents:

```
     fName : "Samuel",
     sName : "Erick Jameson"
```

I want to return the user if the search is by Samuel, Erick, Jameson, Erick Jameson, Samuel Erick etc.

Basically if any word exist in the fName or sName, I want to return it. For now, I have the following query:

```
 Function.lower(Expression.property("fName")).like(Expression.string("%" + searchTermLC + "%"))))
 .or((Expression.property("lName").like(Expression.string("%" + searchTermLC + "%")));
```

my search results are:

```
 Samuel              found
 Erick               found
 Jameson             found
 Erick Jameson       found
```

the following are not found:

```
 Samuel Erick
 Erick Samuel
 Samuel Jameson
```

...

what query would do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes noted in your query above:

1. The open close brackets don't match
2. You forgot about Function.lower(Expression.property("lName")).

I assume when you did your own test, the query syntax was right otherwise you would not have gotten any results.

The results you got are as expected for `like` operator.  If you want the query to include:

```
Samuel Erick
Erick Samuel
Samuel Jameson
```

in your results, you can try the `In` Operator.